# "Mit dem Computer arbeiten"

Tags: word-choice

Ein Satz aus einem Übungsbuch:

> Hast du heute lange **mit dem Computer gearbeitet**? Du siehst müde aus.

Bis jetzt habe ich immer *am Computer/Laptop arbeiten/spielen* gehört. In einem Forum habe ich gelesen, dass wenn man "mit dem Auto fahren" sagen kann, "mit dem Computer arbeiten" ebenfalls möglich sei.
Würdet Ihr dies bestätigen? Kann man im heutigen Sprachgebrauch tatsächlich *Ich habe heute sechs Stunden mit dem Computer gearbeitet* sagen?

Comment: Auf welche andere Redewendung/Floskel bezieht sich "mit dem Auto fahren"? Weil mein Sprachgebrauch diese Varianten kennt: "ich bin Auto gefahren/ ich bin mit dem Auto gefahren/ ich bin im Auto gefahren" - je nachdem, worauf mein Fokus liegt. Ähnlich kann ich einen Unterschied in "mit dem PC" vs "am PC" betonen, ist nur meist eher Gewohnheit, welches von beiden ich nutze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Am* Computer arbeiten

kommt wohl noch aus der Zeit, als der Computer einen festen Platz hatte.

Obwohl das auch im Falle eines Notebooks wohl niemand als falsch betrachten wird, nutzt man den Computer in der Regel als Werkzeug, *mit* dem man arbeitet.

*An* etwas arbeiten bezeichnet außerdem auch das Endprodukt.

> Sie hat heute drei Stunden an ihrer Dissertation gearbeitet.
> Er hat gestern den ganzen Tag am Haus gearbeitet.

*Am* Computer arbeiten könnte also durchaus so verstanden werden, dass jemand einen Computer aufrüstet oder aus Einzelteilen zusammenbaut.

> ... dass wenn man "mit dem Auto fahren" sagen kann, "mit dem Computer arbeiten" ebenfalls möglich sei. Würdet Ihr dies bestätigen?

Dokumente etc. erstellt man eigentlich *mit* dem Computer. Es ist also - um die Frage zu beantworten - auf jeden Fall möglich und keineswegs falsch.

Answer (score 6):

Ja, das kann man sagen.

1. An der, an dem (am)

> An der Werkbank arbeiten
> An der Tiefdruckmaschine arbeiten
> Am Webstuhl arbeiten
> Am Computer arbeiten

Damit ist gemeint, dass man an der großen ortsfesten Maschine steht oder sitzt und dort seine Arbeit verrichtet.

---

2. Mit

> Mit der Bohrmaschine arbeiten
> Mit dem Schweißgerät arbeiten
> Mit dem Schraubenschlüssel arbeiten
> Mit dem Computer arbeiten

Hier ist gemeint, dass man ein Werkzeug benutzt, das leicht an einen anderen Ort bewegt werden kann, und mit Hilfe dieses Werkzeugs sein Werk vollbringt.

---

Die Floskel *am Computer arbeiten* stammt aus der Zeit, als Computer riesige Maschinen waren, die ganze Räume ausfüllten. Heute versteht man unter einem Computer meist einen Laptop, den man überall hin mitnehmen kann.

Comment: Ich sehe jetzt nicht so recht, welche Information deine Antwort hinzufügt, die in meiner nicht schon vorhanden wäre.

Comment: @Olafant: Ich sehe das auch nicht (von ein paar Beispielen abgesehen), aber ich habe deine Antwort erst gelesen, nachdem ich meine gepostet hatte. Das passiert manchmal. Ich hatte den Text bereits fertig und habe gerade nach Bildern gesucht, die ich eventuell den Beispielen hinzufügen hätte können, als ich bemerkt hatte, dass jemand eine Antwort gepostet hat. Ich habe das ignoriert, und habe weiter nach Bildern gesucht, aber leider keine lizenzfreien Bilder gefunden. Dann, ca. 30 bis 40 Minuten nachdem ich mit dem Verfassen der Antwort begonnen habe, habe ich sie dann gepostet.